# multiple sub-questions for function

Tags: functions

I have the following problem:

$$f: \mathbb R\to +\infty $$ and $$f(x) - f(y) = f( x / y) , x,y > 0 $$

a)Show that $$f(1) = 0$$
b)Show that $f$ is one-to-one and that $$f(x)=0$$ has a single solution

c)solve the equation $$ f(x^2 -2) + f(x) = f(5x -6) $$

d) If $f(x) > 0$ for every $x>1$, show that $f$ is strictly increasing at $$(0, +\infty) $$

Thank you

Comment: $f:\mathbb{R}\to +\infty$ what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

$$(a)\,\,\;\;\;\;f(1)=f\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)=f(1)-f(1)$$

$$(b)\;\;\;\;\;x\neq y\Longrightarrow f(1)=0\neq f(x)-f(y)=f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\Longrightarrow \frac{x}{y}\neq 1$$

Take it from here...